# Multicast in the MSC rate for 802.11n and 802.11ac

Tags: openwrt, multicast

Is there any ath10k expert around here? Not sure if I could ask this question here. Otherwise, please direct me to the correct forum.

I would like to know if there is any possible to operate multicast in the MSC rates for 802.11n and 802.11ac?

I am using OpenWRT ath10k for QCA988x radio module on one of manufacturer router board.

Thanks.

Comment: your post begins with the telltale signs of [copy-paste from another SE site](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/37921/3955)

Comment: @grawity: So?  The other question is closed and he was directed here without migration of the question.  He could do without the introductory paragraph... but Network Engineering should have told him that already.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, multicast in 802.11n *must* be sent using one of the 'basic rates', although that could be set to something as high as 54 Mbps.

Low rates are necessary for Wi-Fi multicast because no retransmissions are performed – so the higher link rate, the higher chance that many clients won't receive the multicast frame at all.

Search if your firmware/driver offer an option for "multicast to unicast" aka "multicast enhancement". With it enabled, the AP will send the frame to each recipient individually – although this duplicates data, it also allows the AP to use the highest MCS rate possible for that client.

Comment: The AP have multicast enhancement enabled.